# Specific integral with continuous function

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Let $f: [0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. How can I compute:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2} \right)^2 \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} (xy(1-x)(1-y))^n f(x,y)\, dx\, dy$$
?

Answer (score 1):

$$\iint_{[0,1]^2} x^n (1-x)^n y^n (1-y)^n \,dx\,dy = \left(\int_{0}^{1}z^{n}(1-z)^n\,dz\right)^2=\left(\frac{n!^2}{(2n+1)!}\right)^2$$
hence the limit, by convergence in distribution, is just $\color{red}{f\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}.$

Comment: Could you tell me more about this method? I googled about it, but I can't find any similiar examples.

Comment: @Marcinek665: look for "convergence in distribution". This is an exercise in probability, if we regard the integrand function as a distribution on the unit square.

Answer (score -1):

HINT: Expand $f(x,y)$ in a power series $f(x,y)= \sum_{i,j=0}^\infty a_{ij}x^iy^j$. Then use the Definition of the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

For computing the Limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ you must use $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ for natural number $n$.

Comment: (-1) Continuity does not imply analiticity. It is not always true that we can expand a (bivariate) continuous function as a power series.