# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^2\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (xy(1-x)(1-y))^n f(x,y)dxdy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, continuity, binomial-coefficients

> Note: even though this is technically a duplicate of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170444/specific-integral-with-continuous-function), I'd like further justification on what exactly the claim about "convergence in distribution" in @JackD'Aurizio's answer means, and, if possible, a proof as to why that claim holds.

> Let $f\colon [0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Find $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\dfrac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^2\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (xy(1-x)(1-y))^n f(x,y)\ \mathrm dx\mathrm dy.$$

I think it might be useful to first consider the case where $f$ is a polynomial. By the linearity of integrals, it suffices to consider the case where $f(x,y)=x^ky^l$ for all x,y. Also, Stirling's formula might be useful. There's probably a general formula for evaluating the double integral $I(n,k,l) := \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^{n+k} y^{n+l} (1-x)^n (1-y)^n dxdy.$ It seems possible but tedious to evaluate the latter integral using the Binomial theorem. Alternatively it might be possible to use induction if one can guess the general formula for the integral. For instance in the specific case that $n=0,$ we have the integral $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^k y^l dxdy = \dfrac{1}{(k+1)(l+1)}$. By the linearity of the integral we also have $I(n,k,l) = I(n-1,k+1,l+1) -I(n-1,k+2,l+1)-I(n-1,k+1,l+2)+I(n-1,k+2,l+2).$  Also a special case of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem says that every continuous function $f:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials. But I'm not sure if one can reduce to the case of polynomials.

Comment: The general formula for $I(\cdots)$ is easy because the integral has separable variables. For each separate variable, it is just the beta function.

Comment: Noting that
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x y(1-x)(1-y))^n dx dy = \left(\int_0^1 x^n (1-x)^n dx\right)^2 = \dfrac{(n!)^4}{((2n+1)!)^2}
$$

you can surely say that, if the limit exists, it will correspond to a value of $f$ in $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: This is a dupe but MSE won't let me flag it for some reason: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170444/specific-integral-with-continuous-function.

Comment: @TheBestMagician thanks for the flag, but I hardly understand the answers for the dupe at all. It seems like Jack D'Aurizio is referring to convergence in distribution for probability measures in his answer, but I don't know how to justify that claim.

Comment: @TheBestMagician Ordinary users cannot flag a question with bounty offered as a duplicate. Check [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281182/how-to-deal-with-bounty-questions-that-are-duplicates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### $(xy(1-x)(1-y))^n$ becomes concentrated at $(\frac12,\frac12)$ when $n$ goes bigger$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm d}\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm d}$

$(xy(1-x)(1-y))^n=(x(1-x))^n(y(1-y))^n$ becomes more and more like zero everywhere except at $(\frac12, \frac12)$ comparatively when $n$ goes to infinity. Hence the only significant part of the double integration is when $(x,y)$ is near the point $(\frac12, \frac12)$, where $f(x,y)$ can be viewed as the constant $f(\frac12, \frac12)$. This is how we will compute the limit.

For fixed $n$, $(x,y)\to\frac{(xy(1-x)(1-y))^n}{I_n}$ is [a probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) on $[0,1]^2$, where $I_n=\int_0^1\int_0^1(xy(1-x)(1-y))^n\d x\dd y$. When $n$ goes to infinity, this probability distribution becomes the Dirac measure at $(\frac12,\frac12)$. This is the interpretation in term of probability/[distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) theory.

This answer will use elementary calculus only.

##### Computation by two parts

Consider $g(x,y)=f(x,y)-f(\frac12, \frac12)$.

$g(x,y)$ is a continuous function that is $0$ at $(\frac12,\frac12)$. Let $M>0$ be the maximum value of $|g(x,y)|$ over $[0,1]^2$. For any $\epsilon>0$, there exist $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x,y)|<\epsilon$ for $(x,y)\in [\frac12-\delta, \frac12+\delta]^2$. Assume $\delta<\frac12$; otherwise replace $\delta$ by $\frac14$.

$$\begin{aligned}
&\left|\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (xy(1-x)(1-y))^n g(x,y)\d x\dd y\right|\\
\le&\iint\limits_{(x,y)\in [\frac12-\delta, \frac12+\delta]^2} |(xy(1-x)(1-y))^n g(x,y)|\d x\dd y  \\
&\quad+\iint\limits_{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\\(x,y)\not\in [\frac12-\delta, \frac12+\delta]^2} |(xy(1-x)(1-y))^n g(x,y)|\d x\dd y\\
\le&\iint\limits_{(x,y)\in [\frac12-\delta, \frac12+\delta]^2} (xy(1-x)(1-y))^n \epsilon\d x\dd y + 
\iint\limits_{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\\(x,y)\not\in [\frac12-\delta, \frac12+\delta]^2} (xy(1-x)(1-y))^n M\d x\dd y\\
\le&\iint\limits_{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2} (x(1-x)y(1-y))^n \epsilon\d x\dd y +
M\iint\limits_{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\\(x,y)\not\in [\frac12-\delta, \frac12+\delta]^2} (x(1-x)y(1-y))^n\d x\dd y\\
\le&\left(\epsilon+M\frac{(1-(2\delta)^2}{\delta^2}\left(\frac{1-4\delta^2}{(1-\delta^2)^2}\right)^{n}\right)I_n\\
\end{aligned}$$
where $I_n=\iint\limits_{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2} (x(1-x)y(1-y))^n\d x\dd y $. The last inequality comes from the following computations, where we use $x(1-x)=\frac14-(x-\frac12)^2$ to bound $x(1-x)$ and $y(1-y)$.

$$\begin{aligned}\iint\limits_{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\\ (x,y)\not\in [\frac12-\delta, \frac12+\delta]^2}& (x(1-x)y(1-y))^n \d x\dd y\\
&\le\iint\limits_{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\\ (x,y)\not\in [\frac12-\delta, \frac12+\delta]^2} (\frac14-\delta^2)^n(\frac14)^n \d x\dd y
=(1-(2\delta)^2)(\frac{1-4\delta^2}{16})^n.\\
I_n\ \ge&\iint\limits_{(x,y)\in [\frac12-\frac\delta2, \frac12+\frac\delta2]^2} (x(1-x)y(1-y))^n \d x\dd y\\
&\ge\iint\limits_{(x,y)\in [\frac12-\frac\delta2, \frac12+\frac\delta2]^2} (\frac14-\frac{\delta^2}4)^{2n} \d x\dd y\ge\delta^2(\frac{(1-\delta^2)^2}{16})^{n}.
\end{aligned}$$

Since $0<\frac{1-4\delta^2}{(1-\delta^2)^2}<1$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1-4\delta^2}{(1-\delta^2)^2}\right)^{n}=0$.

So, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{I_n}\left|\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (xy(1-x)(1-y))^n g(x,y)\d\d x\dd y\right|\le\lim_{n\to\infty}(\epsilon+M\frac{(1-(2\delta)^2}{\delta^2}\cdot0)=\epsilon$$
Letting $\epsilon$ approach $0$, we know that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{I_n}\left|\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (xy(1-x)(1-y))^n g(x,y)\d\d x\dd y\right|=0,$$
which means
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{I_n}\int_0^1 \int_0^1(xy(1-x)(1-y))^n f(x,y)\d x\dd y=f(\frac12,\frac12).$$

##### Computation of $I_n$

What remains to do is to compute $I_n$.

Let $I_{i,j}=\int_0^1 x^i(1-x)^j\d x$ for nonnegative integer $i$ and $j$.

$$I_{i,j}=\int_0^1 x^i(1-x)^j\d x=
\left.\frac{x^{i+1}}{i+1}(1-x)^j\right|_{x=0}^{x=1}-\int_0^1 \frac{x^{i+1}}{i+1}(-j)(1-x)^{j-1}\d x\\
=\frac j{i+1}\int_0^1 x^{i+1}(1-x)^{j-1}\d x=\frac j{i+1}I_{i+1, j-1}.
$$

Hence $I_{n,n}=\frac n{n+1}I_{n+1, n-1}=\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}I_{n+2, n-2}=\cdots\\
=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots1}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)}I_{2n, 0}
=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots1}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)}\frac1{2n+1}=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$

$I_n=(I_{n,n})^2=\left(\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}\right)^2$

##### A generalization

Let $g(x,y)\colon[0,1]^2\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous nonnegative function that takes its nonzero maximum value at a single point $(a,b)$. Let $I_n=\int_0^1\int_0^1(g(x,y))^n\d x\dd y$. Then for any continuous function $f(x,y)\colon[0,1]^2\to\Bbb R$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^1\int_0^1(g(x,y))^nf(x,y)\d x\dd y}{I_n}=f(a,b)$$

Comment: @user33096 Thank. I just fixed that lapse. Please check.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to substitute $x=(1+u/\sqrt{n})/2,\ y=(1+v/\sqrt{n})/2$ and apply [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

We get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n\iint_{[-\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}]^2}f_n(u,v)\,du\,dv$, where $$A_n=\frac{(2n+1)!^2}{2^{4n+2}n!^4 n}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac1\pi$$ by Stirling's asymptotics, and $$f_n(u,v)=\left(1-\frac{u^2}{n}\right)^n\left(1-\frac{v^2}{n}\right)^n f\left(\frac12+\frac{u}{2\sqrt{n}},\frac12+\frac{v}{2\sqrt{n}}\right)$$ satisfies the premises of DCT: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(u,v)=f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)e^{-u^2-v^2},\quad\big|f_n(u,v)\big|\leqslant e^{-u^2-v^2}\sup_{0\leqslant x,y\leqslant 1}\big|f(x,y)\big|.$$ Hence, by the theorem, the limit equals $\frac1\pi f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\iint_{[-\infty,\infty]^2}e^{-u^2-v^2}\,du\,dv=f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

As requested, here is a justification of Jack D'Aurizio's claim about convergence in distribution in [the duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170444) discovered by TheBestMagician (thanks to him!).

First note that by Stirling's formula,
$$C_n:=\frac1{\mathrm B(n+1,n+1)}=\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}\sim\frac{2^{2n+1}\sqrt n}{\sqrt\pi}.$$
This is why the  probability measure on $[0,1]$ with density
$$\varphi_n(t):=C_n\,t^n(1-t)^n$$
[converges in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution) to the Dirac measure $\delta_{\frac12},$ namely:
$$\forall x\in\left[0,\frac12\right)\quad\int_0^x\varphi_n(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_{1-x}^1\varphi_n(s)\,\mathrm ds\to0$$
because
$$\forall t\in[0,x]\quad\varphi_n(t)\le C_nx^n(1-x)^n\sim\frac{2\sqrt n}{\sqrt\pi}q^n,\quad\text{where}\quad q:=4x(1-x)<1.$$
As a consequence, the probability measure on $[0,1]^2$ with density $\varphi_n(u)\varphi_n(v)$ converges in distribution to $\delta_{\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)},$ namely:
$$\iint_A\varphi_n(u)\varphi_n(v)\,\mathrm du\mathrm dv\to\delta_{\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)}(A)$$
for every Borel set $A\subset[0,1]^2$ not containing $\left(\frac12,\frac12\right).$

Since convergence in distribution implies [weak convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) , we conclude that for any continuous (hence bounded) function $f:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb R,$
$$\iint f(u,v)\varphi_n(u)\varphi_n(v)\,\mathrm du\mathrm dv\to f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

The expression
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^2(xy(1-x)(1-y))^n= \frac{x^n(1-x)^n\cdot y^n (1-y)^n}{B(n+1, n+1)^2} = f_{n+1, n+1}(x) f_{n+1, n+1}(y)
\end{align*}
where $f_{\alpha, \beta}(x)$ represents the density of a Beta distribution with shape parameters $\alpha, \beta$, and $B(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the Beta function. Changing to a probabilistic interpretation, we can represent the limit as
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[f\begin{pmatrix} X_n \\ Y_n \end{pmatrix}\right]
\end{align*}
where $X_n, Y_n$ both independently follow $\text{Beta}(n+1, n+1)$. By [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Derived_from_other_distributions), we have $X_n \overset{\mathcal{D}}{=} \frac{\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} A_k}{\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (A_k + B_k)}$ and $Y_n \overset{\mathcal{D}}{=} \frac{\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} C_k}{\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (C_k + D_k)}$ for $A_k, B_k, C_k, D_k$ all independently following $\text{Exp}(1)$. By Law of Large Numbers and Sluksky's, $X_n, Y_n \overset{\mathcal{P}}{\rightarrow} \frac{1}{2}$.

Since $f$ is continuous on a closed, bounded interval, $f$ is also bounded. We have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[f\begin{pmatrix} X_n \\ Y_n \end{pmatrix}\right] &=  \mathbb{E}\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f\begin{pmatrix} X_n \\ Y_n \end{pmatrix}\right] && \text{(Dominated Convergence)} \\
&=  \mathbb{E}\left[f\begin{pmatrix} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n \\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} Y_n \end{pmatrix}\right] && \text{(Continuity of $f$)} \\
&=  \mathbb{E}\left[f\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}\right] && \text{(LLN and Slutsky's)}\\
&=  f\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a probabilistic short proof of the statement. Let $(X_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ an i.i.d. sequence of exponential distributions with parameter $\theta$ (the value of $\theta$ is not relevant as we will see, and can be taken as $1$ for example). The following are basic facts in probability:

1. For any $m$ and $k$, $X_1+\ldots + X_k$ and $X_{k+1}+\ldots + X_{k+m}$ are independent random variables with $\operatorname{Gamma}(k,\theta)$ and $\operatorname{Gamma}(m,\theta)$ distributions respectively (easily seen by taking Fourier transform of the convolution of exponentials).
2. If $U$ and $V$ are idependent random variables with distributions $\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha,\theta)$ and $\operatorname{Gamma}(\beta,\theta)$, then
   $\frac{U}{U+V}$ is a $\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ distributed random variable (an application of change of variables for an intergral over $(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$).

It follows that
$$Y_n=\frac{X_1+\ldots + X_n}{(X_1+\ldots + X_n)+(X_{n+1}+\ldots + X_{2n})}$$
is a $\operatorname{Beta}(n,n)$ random variable. By the law of large numbers,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Y_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\tfrac1n(X_1+\ldots+ X_n)}{\tfrac1n(X_1+\ldots+X_n)+\tfrac1n(X_{n+1}+\ldots+X_{2n})}=\frac12$$
almost surely. Consequently, $Y_n\Longrightarrow\delta_{1/2}$ in law (simple application of dominated convergence).

To conclude, consider two independent sequences $(X_n)$ and $(X'_n)$ of i.i.d exponential random variable with parameter $1$, and define $Y_n$ and $Y'_n$ as above. Then $Y_n\stackrel{d}{=} Y'_n$
The joint distribution of $(Y_n,Y'_n)$ is $f_n(u,v)=\Big(\tfrac{\Gamma(2n)}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n)}\Big)^2u^{n-1}(1-u)^{n-1}v^n(1-v)^{n-1}\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]^2}(u,v)$. Thus, $$(Y_n,Y'_n)\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\Longrightarrow}\delta_{1/2,1/2}$$